# filtering a query record source on two date text boxes (beginning and ending date)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a access form whose recordsource is a query.  I want to put two date text boxes on the form and then filter the query for just those records.  Can somebody show me an example how this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

Add two TextBox controls to your Form and set their format to "Sort Date". Then add a Button and on the `Click` event add the following:

```
Private Sub btnFilterForm_Click()
    With Me
        .Filter = "[Date Field] Between #" & Format(.TextBox1.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" _
                                           & Format(.TextBox2.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub
```